# Python typing: passing int to subclass of int

Tags: python, inheritance, python-typing

Here is a minimal demonstration of my problem:

```
class PositiveInt(int):
    def __new__(cls, number: int):
        if number <= 0:
            raise ValueError("number must be positive")
        return super().__new__(cls, number)


class Order:
    def __init__(self, price: PositiveInt) -> None:
        self.price = price


Order(1) # Argument of type "Literal[1]" cannot be assigned to parameter "price" of type "PositiveInt" in function "__init__"
  # "Literal[1]" is incompatible with "PositiveInt"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

Why Pylance throw this error, if 1 is `int` and `PositiveInt` inherits from `int`? How should I fix it? Or what is wrong with my approach and how can I make it better?

Comment: You can't pass an `int` because it could be negative, which isn't a `PositiveInt`. There's no automatic type conversion of literals.

Comment: Because `PositiveInt` inherits from `int`, all instances of `PositiveInt` are instances of `int`. But the converse is not true: not every instance of `int` is an instance of `PositiveInt`. Therefore the typechecker considers it invalid to pass an `int` as a parameter where a `PositiveInt` is required.

Comment: You need to do `Order(PositiveInt(1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code, you should do `Order(PositiveInt(1))`. It's true that `PositiveInt` inherits from `Int`, but you are passing a literal that is an `Int`. The laws of OOP says that, in this case, All `PositiveInt` are `Int`, but not all `Int` are `PositiveInt`